# Deploying to heroku with browser-sync / nodejs "Couldn't open browser"

Tags: node.js, heroku, browser-sync

I've inherited a fairly simple codebase that I am trying to deploy to heroku

Here is part of **package.json** file:

```
...

"engines": {
    "node": "8.1.1",
    "npm": "5.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist/{css/*,js/*,images/*}",
    "autoprefixer": "postcss -u autoprefixer -r dist/css/*",
    "scss": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css src/scss",
    "lint": "eslint src/js || true",
    "lint-scss": "stylelint src/scss/*.scss --syntax scss || true",
    "uglify": "mkdirp dist/js -p && uglifyjs src/js/*.js -m -c -o dist/js/main.min.js",
    "imagemin": "imagemin src/images/* -o dist/images",
    "serve": "browser-sync start --server --files \"dist/css/*.css, dist/js/*.js, **/*.html, !node_modules/**/*.html\"",
    "build:css": "run-s lint-scss scss autoprefixer",
    "build:js": "run-s lint uglify",
    "build:images": "run-s imagemin",
    "build": "run-s build:*",
    "watch:css": "onchange \"src/scss\" -- run-s build:css",
    "watch:js": "onchange \"src/js\" -- run-s build:js",
    "watch:images": "onchange \"src/images\" -- run-s build:images",
    "watch": "run-p serve watch:*",
    "postinstall": "run-s build watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.0.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "eslint": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "imagemin-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "onchange": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "stylelint": "^9.4.0",
    "uglify-es": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "main": ".eslintrc.js"
}
```

and my **Procfile**:

```
web: npm run serve
```

But when I deploy to heroku - the build fails and hangs:

```
remote:        [Browsersync] Access URLs:
remote:         ---------------------------------------
remote:               Local: http://localhost:3000
remote:            External: http://172.16.113.170:3000
remote:         ---------------------------------------
remote:                  UI: http://localhost:3001
remote:         UI External: http://localhost:3001
remote:         ---------------------------------------
remote:        [Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
remote:        [Browsersync] Watching files...
remote:        [Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
```

I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, to fix:

1. remove `"postinstall": "run-s build watch"` from the package.json.
2. modify the serve script by adding `--port $PORT` to it. it should look like this 
   `"serve": "browser-sync start --server --files --port $PORT \"dist/css/*.css, dist/js/*.js, **/*.html, !node_modules/**/*.html\"",`
3. Create a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) on the root of folder. 
   Include the following in the Procfile: `web: npm run build watch`
4. you can locally run the heroku app by the command `heroku local web` or just deploy it and it should work.